# Convert unicode character to corresponding text?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to know is there any way to convert unicode char to its text rather than using static map ?

e.g.
$ -> Dollar Sign ,
A - >Latin Capital Letter A

I wish to do exactly same as **charmap.exe utility.**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I know to do something like that is to use [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/).  I think that the function [`u_charName()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#f6b64ddae2f24a66fc073b9fb1a00602) is what you are looking for.  I'm not a VC++ expert but it looks like you could use something in the [`System.Globalization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abeh092z.aspx) namespace if you are using .NET.  I would assume that the [National Language Support (NLS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319081(v=VS.85).aspx) package has something similar buried in one of the functions.